# How to replace window.confirm with notification.confirm in HYBRID mobileApp(iOS)

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently in my Web app I'm doing As shown in the below Code. 
So What happens after reaching the $window.Confirm compiler waits for response on Alert box and depending on that **Leave** gets true or false.
Finally this method returns that boolean value to its coupled method.

//** IN WEB APP**//

```
function shouldLeave(next) 
                var message =  'Do you wish to leave this Page';
                var leave =  $window.confirm(message); // Return bool value as per user selection

                if (leave) {
                    //Doing my job...
                    reset();
                }
                return leave;
            }
```

Now for Hybrid What I'm doing is:

```
function shouldLeave(next) {
                var message =  'Do you wish to leave this Page';
                var leave =  notification.confirm(message, callbackMethod(),title,[Ok, Cancel]); // Here there is no return value . Return depends on Callback as the callback method gets called depending on user selection

                if (leave) {
                    //Doing my job...
                    reset();
                }
                return leave;
            }

function CallBack(index)
{
switch(index)
{
case 1 :
leave=true; break;
case 2 :
leave=false; break;
default:
leave=-1; break
}
return leave;

}
```

So here after executing the Notification.confirm compiler is not waiting for user response and moving to Next line.(but for Window. Confirm  is was doing so).
So Now my doubt is how to refactor this code so that mu Should leave method will return the proper leave value to its coupled method. Because by the time my **callback** method executes after user interaction in hybrid app **shouldLeave** completes its execution. So its not behaving like $window.confirm functionality.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
function shouldLeave() {
        var message =  'Do you wish to leave this Page';
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            message, // message
            onConfirm,                       // callback to invoke with index of button
            'Confirmation',                  // title
            'Ok, Cancel'                  // buttonLabels
        );
    }


    //on button press, the onConfirm function is called
    function onConfirm(button) {
        //console.log('You selected button ' + button);
        if(button == 1){
            //pressed "Ok"
            console.log("Ok ACTION");
        }
        else if(button == 2){
            //pressed "Cancel"
            console.log("Cancel ACTION");
        }
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks Imran . I know this approach but my requirement is different. Sounds like I need to refactor my code.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
notification.confirm(message, callbackMethod(), title, [Ok, Cancel]);
```

to

```
notification.confirm(message, callbackMethod, title, [Ok, Cancel]);
```

Explanation: 
if you put `callbackMethod()`, it is executed as soon as the execution reach that line
if you put `callbackMethod` withouth the (), you are declaring the function to be executed on the callback.

Comment: But my requirement is the compiler should stop @ notification.confirm till callback method is executed. Just like it happens in case of window.confirm method. but here my compiler is moving to next step.

Comment: then that isn't possible, the code you want to be executed when the callback is executed, has to be inside that callback